# Javascript Array.prototype.reduce() reduces in signe nubmer instead of object

Tags: javascript, reduce

I'm testing a prototype of a method on *Chrome Console* and getting an unexpected result regarding **Array.prototype.reduce()**

Eg for the example bellow

```
let a = [["a",1],["b",1],["c",1]];

let result = a.reduce((acc, e) => acc[e[0]]=e[1], {});
```

the result I expected to have is

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 1,
  "c": 1
}
```

but instead I get the value **1**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need to return accumulator in each iteration.

```js
let a = [["a",1],["c",1],["d",1]];

let result = a.reduce((acc, e) => (acc[e[0]]=e[1], acc), {});
console.log(result)
```

You could also use destructuring assignment on second parameter to get first and second element of each array.

```js
let a = [["a",1],["c",1],["d",1]];

let result = a.reduce((acc, [a, b]) => (acc[a] = b, acc), {});
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Interesting syntax for `(acc[e[0]] = e[1], acc)`, would you mind explaining it? I don't really get how this works TBH... Looks kind of hacky ;)

Comment: @sp00m: It's the comma operator. The left-hand operand is evaluated, then the right-hand side operand is evaluated, and then the result of the comma expression is the result of that right-hand side. Nenad had to put `()` around it so the whole expression is the body of the arrow function. (Personally, much prefer your version with `{}`.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Interesting, thanks for the details. Weird I haven't seen this more often.

Comment: @sp00m: Well, it's fairly hard to read. :-) (But then, many things are at first.) I've never warmed to it, it's too easy to include more or less than you meant in the expression.

Answer (score 3):

Because you need to return the accumulated object from the callback:

```js
let result = a.reduce((acc, e) => {
  acc[e[0]] = e[1];
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 3):

While you **can** use `reduce` for this ([see sp00m's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45859267/157247)), it's not a great fit, and it's clunky and easily forgotten to return `acc` from the callback every time. (And in your case, because you didn't and used a concise arrow, you were returning the result of `acc[e[0]] = e[1]` at each stage.) `reduce` is useful for when the accumulator *changes* through the course of the reduction.

This is really just a case for `forEach`:

```
let a = [["a",1],["b",1],["c",1]];
let result = {};
a.forEach(e => result[e[0]] = e[1]);
```

Comment: Personally I don't like external accumulators and try to avoid them, as I do with external iterators. In fact I find it neat and clean ( [see Nenads answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45859261/2895833) ) instead of clunky, but do agree that its easy to forget (one thing to consider)

Comment: @Xipo: I often like being able to just do `let result = doTheThing()` as well. In fact, in my own work I often have a function for this where it would be something like `let result = a.build({}, (e, o) => o[e[0]] = e[1]);` :-) (`build` being non-enumerable, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code to:

```
let result = a.reduce((acc, e) => {acc[el[0]]=e[1]; return acc}, {});
```

Why:

```
acc[e[0]]=e[1] //this returns 1 not the acc
```